# reduce the amount of duplicated rules in makefile

Tags: makefile

The goal is to specify a build directory where .o and the executable will reside after building the project

currently I've written this Makefile that does this but I have to specify for each object file its directory manually.

```
PROGNAME    = parkingLotApp

CXX         = g++

SRC         = main.cpp \
        parking_car.cpp \
        parking_lot.cpp \
        shader.cpp \
        shader_manager.cpp


OBJS        = main.o \
        parking_car.o \
        parking_lot.o \
        shader.o \
        shader_manager.o \


BUILDIR     = build

CXXFLAGS    = -Wall -c -std=c++11

LDFLAGS     = -Wall

LIBS        = -lGL -lGLEW -lglfw


$(PROGNAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(BUILDIR)/*.o $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $(BUILDIR)/$(PROGNAME) 

main.o: 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCDIR) main.cpp -o $(BUILDIR)/main.o

parking_car.o: 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCDIR) parking_car.cpp -o $(BUILDIR)/parking_car.o

parking_lot.o: 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCDIR) parking_lot.cpp -o $(BUILDIR)/parking_lot.o

shader.o: 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCDIR) shader.cpp -o $(BUILDIR)/shader.o

shader_manager.o: 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCDIR) shader_manager.cpp -o $(BUILDIR)/shader_manager.o


.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm  $(BUILDIR)/*.o $(BUILDIR)/$(PROGNAME)
```

Again, this works as I expected but I want to get rid of manually specifying directory ($(BUILDIR)/someobject.o) for each .o file

I tried this instead of duplicated lines above

```
$(OBJS): 
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCDIR) $(SRC) -o $(patsubst %, $(BUILDIR)/%, $(OBJS))
```

but it gave an error for all build/*.o

saying that

> no such file or directory

Why it does not work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt to combine all of the object file rules failed because the compiler did not know that you wanted to compile all of the source files *separately*.

We start with the object file rules:

```
main.o: 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCDIR) main.cpp -o $(BUILDIR)/main.o

...
```

Then we realize that these rules don't build what they claim to build; this rule claims to build `main.o`, but it actually builds `build/main.o`. This will cause trouble later, so we fix it:

```
$(BUILDIR)/main.o: 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCDIR) main.cpp -o $(BUILDIR)/main.o

...
```

Then we notice that we forgot to tell Make about the prerequisite source files-- Make does not know that it should rebuild this target if `main.cpp` has changed. So we correct that:

```
$(BUILDIR)/main.o: main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCDIR) main.cpp -o $(BUILDIR)/main.o

...
```

Then we use [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) to reduce the redundancy:

```
$(BUILDIR)/main.o: main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCDIR) $@ -o $@

...
```

Then we notice that all of these object-file-building rules have exactly the same command, so we combine them into a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules):

```
$(BUILDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCDIR) $@ -o $@
```

(You could make them into a *static* pattern rule, but this is enough for one day.)

**EDIT:**

We must also change the `PROGNAME` rule to give it the correct name and prerequisites, and use automatic variables:

```
$(BUILDIR)/$(PROGNAME): $(addprefix $(BUILDIR)/, $(OBJS))
    $(CXX) $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@
```

Comment: first thanks for help...but when I do $(BUILDIR)/main.o it does not place the output object in build directory (but with .cpp files instead), whereas without it does, why its like that ? I have to get all the .o and executable within the same dir

Comment: @ampawd: I made a minor error (writing `BUILDDIR` instead of your `BUILDIR`) and a major one (forgetting to correct the `PROGNAME` rule. I will edit. If it still doesn't work, let me know and we'll go through it step by step.